# List of Authors confirmed as ones with a conflict of interest

Tags: research

I remember that I have seen a list of Authors of Health and/ or Trails papers with a conflict of interst. This means their doutful objectivity is confirmed since they are sponsored by the pharmaceutical industry or whatever. 
Anyone who can help me find this list, since I just cannot find it anymore.